# C++ Injecting a dll, do you need threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I'm a little new to it and I don't understand the threading term completely yet, Allthough I know how to make a thread and run programs with multiple threads. What I'm wondering about is that when you create a dll file (c++) and inject it into a process (lets say gamehacking) for instance. Would you need to create threads in the dll file, or is that not going to work? After my understanding the main thread will be running from the host process right? Or how does it work?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create separate threads in your DLL. It depends on what you need to do.

Comment: As "injecting" is not a term that is fixed, it's impossible to say if you need threads. You don't need threads every time, but some injections might need them.

Comment: Ok, but will it work to create threads in a dll file and they will run separetly in the host process? Im at school so I cant test it but the idea just hit me. Or would threads ot make it go faster? Because my exernal program is running very slow because of multithreading allthough my code isn't so optimized yet. So I might make it a dll instead and inject it into the process. But im wondering if i need threads or not

Answer (score 3):

Since you are specifically refering to *injecting* the DLL, I have some input for you additionally to what has already been said.

First, let's make sure that the concepts of threads, processes and modules are clear.

A thread is basically the immediate environment in which code runs. Things like the current state of processor registers and stack variables (e.g. your local variables in functions, in most cases, but also where in the code the execution currently stands) belong to a thread. There are also other resources which often have thread-affinity, such as windows. It depends a lot on the resource in question whether and what kind of thread affinity they have.

Let's assume you write a simple hello world program. It will run in one thread which goes through your program from the beginning to the end and print "Hello World". Now let's assume you would want to write a program which slowly writes "Hello World", one character per second, but in the meantime download a file. Then you could create a second thread and have one thread output "Hello World" slowly, and one thread download the file. This means execution can happen in parallel, with different local state - one thread is currently inside your `printHelloWorld` function and one thread is inside `downloadFile`.

A process is basically a container for one or more threads. It bundles them together in a shared environment which uses the same virtual memory (this means that for example global variables in your code would be accessible from all threads, but this would require careful synchronization to avoid race conditions) and shares resources such as file handles the threads in the process create. So, your hello-world-and-download program from before would have 2 threads in 1 process, sharing the console for example, and being seen in the task manager as one entity.

A module is a file which contains executable code (in most cases, that is) and is loaded into a process. Usually, in a process there are one EXE file and several DLL files loaded as modules. DLL files and EXE files are technically almost the same, but EXE files are meant to be the basis from which a processes starts, and DLL files are meant to be libraries exporting certain functions which can be used by other modules. Since I said modules are loaded into processes, it means that a module is accessible by all threads in the process, and it doesn't have thread-affinity by its own - in our previous example, when the second thread downloads the file, it may be calling into a HTTP-networking DLL, whose code would then run in the second thread. There is a number of modules which is loaded automatically into each process by Windows, and others are probably loaded by certain features of your compiler.

OK, so, back to your question:

> Would you need to create threads in the dll file[...]?

Per se, using a DLL has nothing to do with whether you need to create new threads or not. It depends on what you want to do - if you need to do some time-consuming task in parallel to whatever other code is running, then you would need to create a new thread for it, otherwise there is no need.

> [...]or is that not going to work?

As said, you *can* create new threads if you want (it will work), but it's not a necessity coming with using a DLL.

> After my understanding the main thread will be running from the host process right?

The main thread *of the host process* will of course be in the host process. (Although there is technically no "main thread", since it's perfectly valid to have the first thread in a process create a second one and then terminate, so only the second one would be running anymore, you usually do have the first thread live through the whole lifetime of the process, and you can probably call it the "main thread" in this case.) In which module the currently-running code is located, though, will depend on what the thread is currently doing.

Let me get back to the matter of "injecting": The previous answers appear to have assumed a more "normal" environment where your DLL is just linked to the program and meant to be loaded by it. In this case, your DLL's initialization routine (which is automatically run when a module is loaded into a process) would just be run in the "main thread", probably before the actual work of the process begins.

However, things are a bit different when you inject a DLL. It depends on how you do the injection:

- If you inject the DLL by modifying the imports table of the host EXE, then your DLL will be loaded the "normal" way I just said. So you can expect your initialization routine to run during the process' startup, in the main thread.
- If you inject the DLL by using the AppInit_DLLs registry key, it would be the same.
- Same thing if you inject the DLL by starting the host process suspended, then writing a stub to load the DLL into the processes' memory and using `SetThreadContext` to point the instruction pointer to it.
- If you inject the DLL through means of remotely calling `LoadLibrary` inside the target process, using `CreateRemoteThread`, then however, as the name suggests, *you are creating a new thread* inside the process. In this thread, `LoadLibrary` will load your DLL and also call your initialization routine, so in this case, your initialization routine would indeed run in a new thread other than the "main thread".

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends on what you are planning to achieve using the DLL. If that particular DLL has some static functions / utility class, that just takes an input, doing some calculations / processing and produce an output, then there is no need of threading here.

But if that DLL is going to listen on a socket or write to a file or do the actual work that going to need some parallelism, then you might want to create threads inside that DLL.

Basically you must need to understand, what is that task, that is accomplished by this DLL. A DLL can be linked during compile time as a normal library or it can be loaded dynamically in run-time based on your need / use-case.

To answer your question,

`Would you need to create threads in the dll file, or is that not going to work?`

Ans : Not always. You need to create thread to accomplish some task. That being said, this is not the case always. It is perfectly feasible to run a DLL inside a process, without  having any threads.

`After my understanding the main thread will be running from the host process right? Or how does it work?`

Ans : That's right. Any process you run, there will be one thread by default. If your application is simple enough to be processed by a single thread, then it is a blessing. Keep up with it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cleared some stuff up for me. :p

Comment: Glad about that. You might wanna upvote my answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 1):

Every process has at least one thread. When that process starts, it's possible to link a bunch of functions, or a library, to the memory space of that process. That's what a dll is. The advantage compared to linking directly to the binary is the library only has to exist in one place in the file system and one place in memory while being used by multiple processes. It's a linking technique, similar to how .so files are used in Linux. It has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: Ok, so I should ctually run my program from within the process I'm trying to make a program for, instead of making an external one? I'm making a game hack lol

Answer (score 1):

> Would you need to create threads in the dll file, or is that not going to work?

There wouldn't be any point loading a DLL that didn't contain code that would be run.  That said, there are several ways the DLL code might get run:

- when the DLL is loaded it gets a chance to run some initialisation code
- during initialisation, it might:

  - start one or more threads, which can keep running - perhaps watching for some event that triggers some action on their part
  - register for callbacks from the OS or application, such as setting up signal handlers, keystroke handlers, any type of event handler....
- it might contain functions that the program will look for dynamically and run, mistaking your DLL code for the original versions of those functions that the program came with

Which of these suits your needs depends entirely on what your DLL is trying to achieve, and what's technically necessary to achieve it.  For example, if watching for some memory to have specific content, then modifying it further, it might suffice to have a function in your DLL called by an OS alarm service, resetting itself to go off again later if the triggering memory content is not found.  But, the trigger might be existence of a file, or shared memory service, a socket being created etc..

> After my understanding the main thread will be running from the host process right? Or how does it work?

Yes - threads started within a process - including any DLL initialisation routines - are also within the process.  There are some library functions that may create other processes - such as fork, popen, system - that may contain their own threads.

Comment: Thanks :)        Toofewcharacters